# How to loop through textBox(i) in c#?

Tags: c#, database, dynamic, textbox

I've a situation here . I haven't written the code , as I don't have the idea even to kick it off!. I've 10 textboxes and a button , so when I finish typing into only 3 I'll use only three as the values I'm parsing into these textboxes go into the database.I'm planning to write a query in a for loop and execute it, so that only the text boxes which have value get into the database.

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
 string sql = "Insert Into exprmnt(docid,itemid,doctitle,itemcontent)values("+int.Parse(label6.Text)+","+i+",'"+label5.Text+"','"+textBox[i].Text+"')";

}
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql,con);
  con.Open();

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
```

this is something that I'd want to happen , it's okay if I've empty 'itemcontent' against some itemid 'i'which happens when I save all the text boxes including the ones that don't have any text keyed in.

Comment: You're open for SQL-Injection. Use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Just don't use textboxes for this, it scales horribly and bewilders the user.  Use a DataGridView instead.

Answer (score 1):

To loop through textBox you can create an array of textBoxes you want to loop through:

```
TextBox[] tbs = {textBox1, textBox2, textBox3}; //put all into this array
for(int i = 0; i<tbs.Length; i++)
{
    //use each textBox in here:
    string text = tbs[0].Text; //this is an example of how to get the Text property of each textBox from array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you can use Linq to find the filled textboxes. You're open for SQL-Injection. Use parameters instead of string concatenation:

```
int docid = int.Parse(label6.Text);
String doctitle = label5.Text;
var filledTextBoxes = this.Controls
                             .OfType<TextBox>()
                             .Select((txt,i) => new { Textbox = txt, Index = i })
                             .Where(x => x.Textbox.Text.Length != 0);
if(filledTextBoxes.Any())
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        const String sql = "Insert Into exprmnt(docid,itemid,doctitle,itemcontent)values(@docid, @itemid, @doctitle, @itemcontent)";
        connection.Open();
        foreach(var txt in filledTextBoxes)
        {
            OledDbCommand cmd = new OledDbCommand(sql, connection);
            // Set the parameters.
            cmd.Parameters.Add(
                "@docid", OleDbType.Integer).Value = docid;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(
                "@doctitle", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = doctitle;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(
                "@itemid", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txt.Index;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(
                "@itemcontent", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txt.Textbox.Text;
            try
            {
                int affectedRecords = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        } 
    } // The connection is automatically closed when the code exits the using block.
}
```

Note that i've used the [`using-statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to ensure that the connection gets disposed(closed).

Comment: ?itemcontent
The name 'itemcontent' does not exist in the current context
?itemid
The name 'itemid' does not exist in the current context                                                             these are the values I wanted to be stored in the db. But they aren't getting saved.I used break points while the loop was running. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to replace the `@` with `?`. Have a look at this thread: http://forums.asp.net/t/1583540.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

It worked finally!!!
@yogi thanks!

the code that worked is

```
List<TextBox> textBoxList = new List<TextBox>();
          textBoxList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox1.Text });
          textBoxList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox2.Text });
          textBoxList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox3.Text });
          textBoxList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox4.Text });



          for (int n = 1; n<4; n++)
          {

              string sql = "Insert Into exprmnt (docid,itemid,doctitle,itemcontent) values(" + int.Parse(label6.Text) + "," + n + ",'" + label5.Text + "','" + textBoxList[n].Text+ "')";

              OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);

              connection.Open();

              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              connection.Close();
          } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your textbox controls to a list.. then loop over the list.

```
List<TextBox> textBoxList = new List<TextBox>();

for (int i = 0; i < textBoxList.Count; i++) {
    // .. do your thing here, using textBoxList[i].Text for the value in the textbox
}
```

Also, as Tim Schmelter pointed out.. you're open for SQL injection when concatenating your queries like that.

Comment: I got the textBoList.Count as '0' so the loop breaks there ! . I have five textboxes in my form though.